# weird growing animation with inline-block

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some divs with in a div as inline-block. Now, when I animate them to grow, the rest go down and then go up to their original location. I have maintained all the margin, height, width and all - because, the final position is what I want. It is just the animation is bothering me. Any help ?

Here is an example on jsfiddle. Same is happening with my original code.

http://jsfiddle.net/7Wq6v/

```
$("#main > div").hover(function(){
    $(this).animate({height: "4em", width: "4em", margin: "1em", lineHeight: "4em"},200);
}, function() {
    $(this).animate({height: "2em", width: "2em", margin: "2em", lineHeight: "2em"},200);
});
```

PS : this happens only when the inline-blocks have text or anything else in it, if it is empty, it does not show that weird animation.

Comment: If i were you, i would use CSS3 transition instead: http://jsfiddle.net/7Wq6v/5/

Comment: sorry, I don't know CSS3 much. :( anyway thanks for help ! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: middle;` to your CSS.

```
#main > div {
    display : inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/8wBhT/